# methods as properties of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

i need to create a javascript function with a private variable that has setter and getter methods. i tried:

```
function createSecretHolder(secret) {
  this._secret = secret;
  var getSecret = function(){
    return this._secret;
  }
  var setSecret = function(secret){
    this._secret = secret;
  }
}
```

and a version with:

```
this.getSecret = function()...
```

and

```
this.seSecret = function()...
```

it is not passing the test suite on code wars. something like

```
var obj = createSecretHolder(secret);
obj.getSecret();
obj.setSecret(newSecret);
```

and others which are hidden. I get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSecret' of undefined and another cannot call method setSecret

Answer (score 0):

`createSecretHolder()` doesn't `return` a value so `createSecretHolder(secret)` returns `undefined`.

So `var obj = createSecretHolder(secret);` sets `obj` to undefined. Hence the error "Cannot read property 'getSecret' of undefined" when you try to access `obj.getSecret()`.

Even if it returned an object, you have declared `getSecret` using `var` inside a `function`. Variables described that way are scoped to the function. So when you try to access it outside the function, as you do in `obj.getSecret()`, that won't work.

You also seem to misunderstand how `this` works. It will not create a private variable.

There are a number of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
function createSecretHolder(mySecret) {
    var secret = mySecret;
    return {
      getSecret: function(){
        return secret;
      },
      setSecret: function (mySecret){
        secret = mySecret;
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: And also argument `secret` is not a string and, probably, not defined :)

Comment: @Trott i'm only supposed to return the value of secret when getSecret is called, so what can I return from createSecretHolder and what's the proper way to add get and set methods to the Object so they are accessible outside the function?

Comment: @Cheery secret is passed in like var obj = createSecretHolder(6); or var obj = createSecretHolder("ILikePizza"); I don't understand what you mean it is not a string and is probably undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you use a [Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) to create an object you need to use the `new` keyword.

Inside your constructor you set a property with `this._secret = secret`. This is accessible from outside. It should be `var _secret = secret`.

Also you create local functions inside your object to get/set `_secret`. They should be methods of the object. See below.

```
// object constructor
function createSecretHolder(secret) {
    // local variable. it isn't accessible from outside
    var _secret = secret;
    // method to get the secret
    this.getSecret = function() {
        return _secret;
    }
    // method to set the secret
    this.setSecret = function(secret){
        _secret = secret;
    }
}
// create new "createSecretHolder" object
var secret = new createSecretHolder("secret 1");

secret.getSecret(); // returns "secret 1"
secret.setSecret("secret 2");
secret.getSecret(); // returns "secret 2"
```

Comment: i see what you're saying. However, there is one simple example test provided which is var obj = createSecretHolder(5); which doesn't use the new keyword. I don't know what to return to obj or if javascript just sets obj equal to the function itself. I don't really understand the "everything is objects and everything is functions" thing in javascript yet.

Comment: @user137717 You can use the approach [Trott](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26436083/2202732) mentioned. It doesn't require the `new` keyword. The `createSecretHolder` function returns an object with methods to get/set local `secret` variable. I haven't used that approach before, but it works. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oLa43vLp/)

Answer (score 0):

Look into prototypejs OO programming.

If you can't use prototypejs because of jQuery conflicts, there is a version of it only with OO support here: https://github.com/Prescia/Prototypejslt

Your could would look like:

```
createSecretHolder= Class.create();
createSecretHolder.prototype = {
    _secret: 0,
    othervariable: true,
    initialize: function(inSecret) { // this is the constructor on prototypejs
        this._secret = inSecret;
    }
}

// Create instance:
var myInstance = new createSecretHolder(5);
// so this should alert "5":
alert(myInstance._secret);
```

I can't live without prototypejs Object Orientation, so I often use this light version that won't conflict with other stuff